# Reload the modal body everytim modal window is opened

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Right now if I do some changes in the modal body (inside html) then those changes don't show in the browser upon refreshing. By googling I got to know that modal is attached once it has been declared and need to remove content each time. But i am looking for method that I can use to do that. I tried to use removeData() but did not worked. Here is the snippet of JS

```
    function enroll(){
      var options = {
        controller: cntl,
        templateUrlpath: 'blahblah.html'
      };
      return $uiModal.open(options).result;
    }
```

This is some content of html:

```
    <div class="modal-body">
     <div class="tabbable"> <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
       <li class="required active">
       <a href=""
         data-target="#nodeInfo"
         data-toggle="tab"
         translate>node info</a></li>
       <li ng-if="!ctrl.driverProperties" class="disabled">
       <a data-target="#nodeDetails"
       translate>Node Details</a></li>
       </div>
       </div>
```

(don't look for format, this is just to give an idea of small portion of html)
Thanks, your inputs would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I figured that the problem was not in the code change but just need to clear my cache.

Comment: In Chrome, you can use `CTRL+SHIFT+R` to perform a full reload, which usually avoids this problem

Comment: Good to know, I am running firefox, and I am thinking why not i use chrome, ;P. Thanks